# How to test for email injection

Tags: php, email, filter, code-injection

I'm using the php mail function and I have a form with the name field, phone field, email field and message field which is a text area. The email field (along with the name and phone field) displays in the message and isn't used to send an email to that address. The To: fields and subject: fields and From: header are static in the script and is designed to always be the same.

I was recently trying to try email injection to my own script so I can then know if my preventative measures are working or not.

I've tried putting in the fields 
%0ATo:mysecondemailaddress@provider.com and also %0ACc:mysecondemailaddress@provider.com, but the email doesn't even send to the proper email address at all. I was just wondering what is the correct method to do this, and also when I am using preventative methods such as identifying strings and either removing them or denying the email from being sent what characters such as % should I also be on the look out for?

Comment: Hiya, 

Is there any reason you're not using a CAPTCHA?  

A spambot could crawl your site, see the contact form and manually send post data to the form's action.  It will then be able to spam whoever would receive the form contact information.

If you want to play with this yourself you could set up a test with [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) or any other library that makes it easy for you to send post data to your form.

It doesn't sound to me that you're particularly vulnerable to email injection, if you're hard-coding the recipient or accepting file uploads.

Comment: I'm planning to have captcha to prevent a spambot from sending off random forms but I am trying to do is protect myself from malicious users but thanks for the answer anyway I'll check Snoopy out.

Comment: I think with email injection you're referring to header injection. The php [`mail` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) has some documentation of how additionally headers can come into the email.

Comment: The article didn't really address injection into headers through form inputs though

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like using the form to directly enter the injection works very well. I'm using [the following](https://github.com/ciplit/Shu-Er/blob/master/php/one_true_form_mailer/header_injection_test.php) to test out a mailer I'm putting together, it posts the data from the script. The `$postData` will have to be modified to suit your form. This just BCCs a 'victim':

```
<?php

    $postData = 
        'contactname=Lord+Sauron&'.
        'email=darklord@ciplit.com.au%0ABcc:frodo@ciplit.com.au'.
        '&message=Sorry+about+that+whole+ring+thing.+No+hard+feelings%3F';

    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/onetrueformmailer.php';

    $result = do_post_request($url, $postData);

    echo($result);




    // http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/
    function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null) {
        $params = array('http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $data
        ));
        if ($optional_headers !== null) {
            $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
        }
        $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
        $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
        if (!$fp) {
            throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
        }
        $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
        if ($response === false) {
            throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
        }
        return $response;
    }

?>
```